# MAGENTO 2 Prototype.js each

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-sign-on, prototype, magento2

I'm developing a module for magento2, with my own views for admin panel and I have problem with Prototype.js method each. It doesn`t work properly with my views, which was developed with Vue.js. Can I update Prototype.js in my extension? Current version of Prototype is '1.7' and I need an update to '1.7.1' so my views could actually work.